# Do adsense estimated earnings appear sometimes with delay?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, error-reporting

Do adsense estimated earnings appear sometimes with delay ? For example yesterday I had a lot of traffic in my block, because I posted it in the social media  (I saw in the block statistics a huge elevation in views). However my adsense account does not show a change in views and earnings. It shows the same number of views as in the previous day. How much time is needed for the new views and new clicks on advertisements to appear in the adsense report ?

Comment: Adsense is not real-time and yes you should expect a delay of those being visible, furthermore you should expect some figures to change throughout the month, hence they use 'estimated earning'.